# Парсинг вакансий с HH на русском

Tags: json, парсер, r

Прошу помочь! Код работает,но когда добавляю кириллицу, перестает выгружать данные. Как спарсить, например: Специалистов по персоналу?

Пример рабочего кода:

```
    {vacanciesdf <- data.frame(
  Name = character(),  # Название компании
  Name = character(), # Название вакансии
  Currency = character(), # Валюта
  From = character(), # Минимальная оплата
  Area = character(), # Город
  Requerement = character(), # Требуемые навыки
  responsibility = character(), 
  stringsAsFactors = T) 
for (pageNum in 0:5) { # Всего страниц
  data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'HR\"&page=", pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, # Город
    data$items$salary$currency, # Валюта
    data$items$salary$from, # Минимальная оплата
    data$items$employer$name, # Название компании
    data$items$snippet$requirement,# Требуемые навыки
    data$items$snippet$responsibility,
    data$items$name)) 
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(3)}
```

Пример нерабочего:

```
 {vacanciesdf <- data.frame(
      Name = character(),  # Название компании
      Name = character(), # Название вакансии
      Currency = character(), # Валюта
      From = character(), # Минимальная оплата
      Area = character(), # Город
      Requerement = character(), # Требуемые навыки
      responsibility = character(), 
      stringsAsFactors = T) 
    for (pageNum in 0:5) { # Всего страниц
      data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'Специалист+персоналу\"&page=", pageNum))
      vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
        data$items$area$name, # Город
        data$items$salary$currency, # Валюта
        data$items$salary$from, # Минимальная оплата
        data$items$employer$name, # Название компании
        data$items$snippet$requirement,# Требуемые навыки
        data$items$snippet$responsibility,
        data$items$name)) 
      print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
      Sys.sleep(3)}
```

Заранее спасибо!

P/S За исходный код спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/279552/alexander-botvin

Comment: Как именно перестаёт работать? Добавьте текст ошибки.

Comment: @Alexshev92 Ошибки нет, скрипт отрабатывает. Но датафрейм с результатами - пустой.

Comment: Странно, заменил, "Специалист" на "Инженер" и у меня код заработал.

Comment: Хотя если просто вставить строку запроса в браузер, видно, что данные возвращаются

Comment: Попробовал) и правда с инженером работает. А со специалистом нет

Comment: Если написать инженер с маленькой буквы, то тоже не работает)) Это загадка!

Comment: @Alexshev92 ого!!! Если вставить вместо специалист+персоналу вот это:
%5C%22%27%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83
то работает!!!

Comment: Ура! сделал костыль и все получилось. Нужно переводить в URL из Windows-1251
@Alexshev92 Если интересно, то вот костыль, который я родил:
site <- "https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'"
Keyword <- "Менеджер+по+персоналу"
pagenumber <- "\"&page="
Keyword_UTF8 <- iconv(Keyword,"Windows-1251","UTF-8")
Keyword <- curlEscape(Keyword_UTF8)
url1 <- paste0(site,Keyword,pagenumber)
Url2 <-gsub("%2B","+",url1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил костыль, который переводит ключевые слова, по которым идет поиск, из Windows-1251 в URL.

```
# Scrap vacancies
site <- "https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'"
Keyword <- "Менеджер+по+персоналу"
pagenumber <- "\"&page="
Keyword_UTF8 <- iconv(Keyword,"Windows-1251","UTF-8")
Keyword <- curlEscape(Keyword_UTF8)
url1 <- paste0(site,Keyword,pagenumber)
Url2 <-gsub("%2B","+",url1)
```

Дальше все также

```
vacanciesdf <- data.frame(
  Name = character(),  # Название компании
  Name = character(), # Название вакансии
  Currency = character(), # Валюта
  From = character(), # Минимальная оплата
  Area = character(), # Город
  Requerement = character(), # Требуемые навыки
  responsibility = character(), 
  stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Ну а здесь вместо собственно адреса - результат костыля Url2

```
for (pageNum in 0:4) { # Всего страниц
  data <- fromJSON(paste0(Url2, pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, # Город
    data$items$salary$currency, # Валюта
    data$items$salary$from, # Минимальная оплата
    data$items$employer$name, # Название компании
    data$items$snippet$requirement,# Требуемые навыки
    data$items$snippet$responsibility,
    data$items$name)) 
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(3)
}
```